# Creating dual lines with one line in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sld, line

Im trying to figure if it is possible to create a two lines from one line say for instance a road. One to create the out lines as an underlaying color while another line creates a top color but a different color.

I would like to try and have the roads look like something below.

[image: raods]

Im not 100% sure how to go about doing it as I aslo have them in different zoom levels and at the furtherst zoom levels they don't need the one color.

my SLD looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>M_rds</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>2000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">
                <ogc:Literal>#fee89c</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
                <ogc:Literal>14</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name ="stroke-linecape">round</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <MinScaleDenominator>2001</MinScaleDenominator>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>4000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">
                <ogc:Literal>#Fee89c</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
                <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name ="stroke-linecape">round</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <MinScaleDenominator>4001</MinScaleDenominator>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>8000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">
                <ogc:Literal>#Fee89c</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
                <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name ="stroke-linecape">round</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <MinScaleDenominator>8001</MinScaleDenominator>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>16000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">
                <ogc:Literal>#Fee89c</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
                <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name ="stroke-linecape">round</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <MinScaleDenominator>16001</MinScaleDenominator>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>32000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">
                <ogc:Literal>#Fee89c</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
                <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name ="stroke-linecape">round</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <MinScaleDenominator>32001</MinScaleDenominator>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>64000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">
                <ogc:Literal>#Fee89c</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
                <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name ="stroke-linecape">round</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
      <!--Road Labels-->
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>64000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#Fee89c</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>r_name</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <LinePlacement/>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Halo>
              <Radius>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </Radius>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name ="Fill">#Fee89c</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name= "Fill-opacity">0.85</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Halo>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Tahoma</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-normal">normal</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">90</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">400</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="repeat">150</VendorOption>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I know tht you can do case lines and have tried to follow the way they have done it here:
[geserver lines](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/lines.html).

Answer (score 1):

Roads are usually rendered with a case colour in first run and a smaller fill colour inside to get nice fittings at road junctions.

And you have to choose line widths for almost every zoom level.

You will have to do a lot of extra calculating if you want to achieve that with offsetted lines.

Comment: Perhaps these SLD files can be used as templates and examples https://github.com/ROGUE-JCTD/geoserver-osm-styles

Comment: There is a bunch of SLD's collected from around the web [here](https://github.com/MarkwareDOTNet/SLD-s) that maybe of use showing how the styling is done